# Tab opened for printing perpetually shows "loading" icon

Tags: javascript, gwt

My GWT JavaScript app prints reports by opening a new browser window programmatically, filling it with the report I want to print, and then calling window.print:

```
native void openPrintWindow(String contents) /*-{
    var printWindow = window.open("", "PrintWin");
    if (printWindow && printWindow.top) {
        printWindow.document.write("<html><head><title>Report Card Print Window</title></head><body>");
        printWindow.document.write(contents);
        printWindow.document.write("</body></html>");
        printWindow.print();
    } else {
        alert("The print feature works by opening a popup window, but our popup window was blocked by your browser.  If you can disable the blocker temporarily, you'll be able to print here.  Sorry!");
    }
}-*/;
```

This works well, except that the icon in the title bar never changes from its initial swirling loading icon.  How can I get it to realize that it's done loading?

I assume the problem is that it's not actually downloading anything, so it never "finishes," exactly.  Is there something I can call like `document.finalize` or anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to call `document.close()` after the last `document.write` call.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write#Notes